# UIActivityViewController not displaying URL

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` to share an URL and a string. The URL is not showing anymore, and I can't explain why:

Here is my code:

```
NSString *shareString = @"blabla string.";
NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareUrl, shareString, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[activityViewController setValue:@"Blabla." forKey:@"subject"];
activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add "http://" to your link.

NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];